# Reload div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem: In my PHP page inside div there is a list of partner details are listed and when i add another partner through jquery i need to show that partner also into the above list ,if the addition is success we need to reload..

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<$partnerCount;$i++){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='<?php echo $partnerData[$i]['PARTY_RELATIONSHIP_ID'];?>' name='party_relation[]'></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['partnerCode'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['partnerName'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['PARTY_ROLE_NAME'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['phone'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['address1'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['address2'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['city'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['state'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partnerData[$i]['zip'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell how you can do it without your client sided stuff, however I guess you could do something like:

```
PHP:
<div id="partners">
    <?php include("TheFileYouShowAbove.php") ?>
</div>

JS:

//Callback from the ajax request where you add a new user
function(data){
    if(data == "success") //This has to be put out by your PHP script
        $("#partners").load("TheFileYouShowAbove.php");
}
```